# Maven build using org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.3.0:java2ws: Argument list too long

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I have a maven project which is building fine on local but failing on gitlab ci/cd pipeline.
The error which is coming as follows:

```
25869 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
925869 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
925870 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
925870 [INFO] Total time:  15:24 min
925871 [INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-08T10:38:11Z
925871 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
925891 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.3.0:java2ws (generate-rec-data-service-wsdl) on project descapreusables-server: Error while executing process.
925898 [ERROR] Try to run this goal using <fork>true</fork> and <classpathAsEnvVar>true</classpathAsEnvVar>.
925905 [ERROR] Command line was: /usr/java/openjdk-11/bin/java --add-exports=jdk.xml.dom/org.w3c.dom.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED -DexitOnFinish=true -cp /builds/arcesium/internal/fiatech/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-java2ws-plugin/3.3.0/cxf-java2ws-plugin-3.3.0.jar:/builds/arcesium/internal/fiatech/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri/2.3.0/jaxws-ri-2.3.0.pom:/builds/arcesium/internal/fia

The final error is coming as **: Cannot run program "/bin/sh" (in directory "/builds/arcesium/internal/fiatech/performa/descap/DESCap-Reusables/src/modules/server/target"): error=7, Argument list too long**
```

The command which its building is very huge but on local its not happening.

The gitlab ciYaml file is as :

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"

  #MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"
  #MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  #MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"


# This template uses jdk8 for verifying and deploying images
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

stages:
  - build
  #- test

build:
  image: "674283286888.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/core-infra/openjdk-maven:3.8.1-openjdk11"
  stage: build
  tags:
    - identity-mnrltdev
  #before_script:
  #  - yum -y install maven
  #  - mvn -version  
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls -ltr 
    - mvn clean package  -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true -s settings.xml
    #- mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: probably you are using different OS then your build machine. Or something else is different like bash version.